# Referencing Web Api Locally from serperate MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following Web Api

```
public class ApiTestController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    [HttpGet]
    public string UploadImage(int id)
    {
        return "You entered = " + id;
    }
}
```

which when run and I enter /api/ApiTest/3 it hits it and returns You entered 3

Now in my seperate MVC application I'm trying to reference the same api method by doing the following

```
 private const string WebUrl = "http://localhost:1769/api/ApiTest/";

    //
    // GET: /Home/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            var test = GetInvoiveNo(3);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        return View();
    }

    public string GetInvoiveNo(int id)
    {
        var uri = WebUrl + id;
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            Task response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<string>(response.ToString()).Result;
        }
    }
```

But I get the error:

> one or more errors occurred

so I take a look into the inner exception and this is what it says:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0."}

Now I'm not sure what I've done wrong here so if someone can kindly tell me or give me a simple example I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What is the value of `response.ToString()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your response is not in proper format.

In below code you try to user response.ToString() which is wrong and you have to user result of response.

```
public string GetInvoiveNo(int id)
    {
        var uri = WebUrl + id;
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<string>(response.Result).Result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have just tried your code but I get a red error line under .Result it says cannot resolve symbol 'Result'

Comment: see my update. I have changed to var response from Task response.

Comment: Just noticed you edited the our answer let me try quick